# How to setup Vite + React + Typescript in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vite, react-tsx

Creating a new React app using Vite, VSCode is not recognizing generated tsx files, showing squiggles everywhere. What am I doing wrong??

[image: VSCode showing squiggles for the entire code]

Here are the steps I'm doing:

`yarn create vite@latest`

Give a project name "my-app"
Framework: React
Variant: TypeScript

Now, for VSCode, according to [Yarn doc](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode), I've installed [ZipFS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs) then:

`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

`Ctrl+Shift+P` then Select Typescript version...VSCode version 5.5.0-dev.20240314 (I've installed [ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) aswell) .

After that, tsx files are still not recognized.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Pushkin Several error messages, cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307), Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Comment: Could just be a faulty install. Try deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and try `yarn install` again.